# Angular: ng-click with dynamic variable

Tags: angularjs

I have an index page displaying a table of all the 'acts' in my db. Basically, what I'm trying to do is this: instead of loading a new view when I want to update one of the acts, I want to render a partial just below that act's row that can be submitted.

Now, I'm guessing if I use ng-click with a static variable name:

```
 ng-click="updateActShow=true" ng-show="updateActShow"
```

it will render an update partial for all of the acts. Thus, I want to use a variable name that includes the id of the act being updated:

```
ng-click"updateActShow[act.id]=true" ng-show="updateActShow[act.id]".
```

I've been trying to do this with an array. But I can't get it to work as I'd like.

Here's my code:

*acts/templates/index.html*

```
<div class="actions_body">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Listing Actions</h2>

    <div class="body">
      <table class>
        <thead>
          <tr class="row">
            <th class="col-md-2 active">
              <label>Name</label>
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-5">Description</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Inspires</th>
            <th colspan="2" class="col-md-2">Modify</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="row" ng-repeat="act in acts">
            <td class="col-md-2"><a href="" ng-click="linkToShowAct(act)">{{act.name}}</a></td>
            <td class="col-md-5">{{act.description}}</td>
            <td class="col-md-2">{{act.inspires}}</td>
            <td><button ng-click="updateActShow(act)">Edit</button></td>
            <td><button ng-click="deleteAct(act)">Delete</button>
          </tr>

          <div ng-show="updateActShowArr[act]" id="updateAct">
            <div ng-include="'acts/templates/_form.html'"></div>
          </div>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <br>

      <button ng-click="newActShow=true">New Action</button>
      <button ng-click="newActShow=false">Hide</button>

      <div ng-show="newActShow" id="newAct">
        <div ng-include="'acts/templates/_form.html'"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*acts/templates/_form.html*

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="ActsController">
  <form class="form-inline" ng-submit="addAct()">
    <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
      <label for="newActname">Name</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="newAct.name" id="newActname" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
      <label for="newActdescription">Description</label>
      <input type="textarea" ng-model="newAct.description" id="newActdescription" placeholder="Description" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
      <label for="newActinspires">Inspires</label>
      <input type="number" ng-model="newAct.inspires" id="newActinspires" placeholder="Inspires" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
      <input type="submit" value="+" class="btn btn-success">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

*acts/controllers/ActsController.js*

```
controllers = angular.module('controllers');

controllers.controller('ActsController', [
    '$scope', 
    '$routeParams', 
    '$location', 
    '$resource', 
    function($scope,$routeParams,$location,$resource) {

        var Act = $resource('/acts/:actId', {
            actId: "@id",
            format: 'json'
        },  {
            'create': {
                method: 'POST'
            }
        });

        $scope.acts = Act.query();

        $scope.addAct = function() {
            act = Act.save($scope.newAct, function() {
                $scope.acts.push(act);
                $scope.newAct = '';
            });
        }

        $scope.deleteAct = function(act) {
            act.$delete();
            $scope.acts.splice($scope.acts.indexOf(act), 1);
        }

        var updateActShowArr = new Array();
        $scope.updateActShow = function(act) {
            updateActShowArr[act] = true;
            $scope.updateActShowArr = updateActShowArr;
        }

        $scope.linkToShowAct = function(act) {
            return $location.path('/acts/' + act.id);
        } 
}]);
```

Comment: `ng-repeat` for each variable `act` will not be accessible outside `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like `updateActShow` is a function, not a variable. That would make it

```
updateActShow(act.id)
```